Do gastropelecid hatchet fish have powered flight?
These sites contradict each other:
Source 1 claims that hatchet fish do not fly, but simply jump out of the water instead:

'Species that were once thought to have powered flight, the
Pantodontidae and the Gasteropelecidae. The Pantodontidae currently
contains only one species, Pantodon buchholizi, the African Butterfly
Fish while the Gasteropelecide contains nine species including the
Marbled Hatchet Fish, Carnegiella strigata. Both these species have
deep bodies with a lot of muscular support for their enlarged pectoral
fins, or in the case of Pantodon, pectoral and pelvic fins. It is now
considered that both these species simply jump, if somewhat
spectacularly, out of the water.'

whereas Source 2 says they fly with their tail:

'Investigations using high-speed cameras have since shown that this supposed ‘flight’ is in fact initially a jump which then becomes true powered flight... The buzzing noise, previously wrongly interpreted as the sound of flapping pectoral fins, in fact comes from the tail fin as it beats around 40 times a second during flight!'

and Source 3, finally, claims that they fly with their pectoral fins:

'So while there are many fish that can glide if they jump out of the water at speed, not least of all the celebrated marine flying fish, only the hatchets have true, powered flight. By rapidly fluttering their pectoral fins, they can extend their jumps out of the water to cover several meters.'


Do not worry, I won’t delete my comments

I can add to @JiminyCricket 's comments that comments are volatile; they can be deleted without further notice (I just did so for a bunch of them because they were obsolete); I have added the links and quotations you provided in the comments to your post. Excellent research +1

Although I think, in the end, it comes down to the definition of flight: what is flight? As discussed previously, the difference between powered flight and gliding is the flight stroke, which produces thrust in true flyers. Gliders, then, do not produce thrust; they do not flap their wings. This link differentiates between flyers, gliders and parachuters in terms of terrestrial critters. In fish, a more specific search for terminology is needed
